# How do i restore the x86 Visual Studio Android AVD

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 I went to edit the avd **VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone.avd** and when i tried to save it gave me an error and then deleted the AVD

Trying to restore it via the Visual Studio setup does nothing so I am wondering how can i get this back again? Is it downloadable somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Went to add KeyBoard support, and the profile got deleted/disappeared from Visual Studio and the .Android/avd folder.  I initiated a repair of Visual Studio and the missing file and folder came back.